# Specifying associatedtype in child protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

Is there any way to define the associatedtype in the child protocol and then use the child protocol as a type of an iVar ?

This is what I need to achieve:

```
protocol Coordinator {
    associatedtype ResultValue
    associatedtype ResultError

    func start(completion: @escaping (Result<ResultValue, ResultError>) -> Void)
}

protocol DownloadPermissionCoordinator: Coordinator {
    associatedtype ResultValue = String
    associatedtype ResultError = DownloadPermissionCoordinatorError
}

protocol SomeOtherCoordinator: Coordinator {
    associatedtype ResultValue = Int
    associatedtype ResultError = SomeOtherCoordinatorError
}
```

And then to be able to use it like this:

```
final class MyTestClass {
    private let downloadPermissionCoordinator: DownloadPermissionCoordinator
    private let someOtherCoordinator: SomeOtherCoordinator

    init(downloadPermissionCoordinator: DownloadPermissionCoordinator,
         someOtherCoordinator: SomeOtherCoordinator) {
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        self.someOtherCoordinator = someOtherCoordinator
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, Swift does not consider that my child coordinator protocols can be used as type constraints.

Modifying it like this:

```
protocol Coordinator2 {
    func start<ResultValue, ResultError>(completion: @escaping (Result<ResultValue, ResultError>) -> Void)
}
```

Unfortunately does not serve the purpose.

I'm trying to avoid the delegate on the concrete coordinator protocols, but it doesn't seem like I can have a generic closure. Any suggestions?

p.s. Just to exemplify the use of a coordinator I've added the below incomplete code

```
final class DownloadPermissionCoordinatorImpl: DownloadPermissionCoordinator {
    private let rootViewController: UIViewController
    private let userPermissionService: UserPermissionService

    init(rootViewController: UIViewController,
         userPermissionService: UserPermissionService) {
        self.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.userPermissionService = userPermissionService
    }

    func start(completion: @escaping (Result<String, ()>) -> Void) {
        guard !userPermissionService.allowsCelularDownload else {
            completion(.success)
            return
        }

        let alertController = ...
        rootViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension MyTestClass {
    func doStuffIfAllowed() {
        downloadPermissionCoordinator.start { result in
            switch result {
            case .success: download()
            case .failure: dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You almost certainly don't want protocols here at all. Looks like you probably want generic structs, or more likely, just closures. How that's implemented depends on your goals. Why are you passing a "coordinator" rather than just passing the `start` function?

Comment: @RobNapier the coordinator protocol is designed to basically just make sure any coordinator has the start function. But different coordinators would have injected different services as well as rootViewController and they need to be class instances as they can be passed around as weak parentCoordinator or other scenarios.

Comment: @RobNapier I've added an example of usage.

Comment: This doesn't match your protocol. Nothing in your protocol requires anything but the `start` method. If you were passing `DownloadPermissionCoordinatorImpl` to a method that accepts `DownloadPermissionCoordinator`, the only method that can be called is `start`. So why not pass `start`. Nothing in your protocol would allow `weak` (and I suspect shouldn't)

Comment: The name `DownloadPermissionCoordinatorImpl` also makes me very curious. How many `DownloadPermissionCoordinator` implementations are in your system? If the answer is less than 3, do you *really* need a protocol at all? This feels like "generic for generic sake" which is always a mistake in Swift.

Comment: The point of protocols-with-associated-types is to add new methods to types. It is not to invent generic types that can be handed around. If you're trying to use PATs as types, rather than just extension methods for existing types, then you're misusing them and you almost certainly meant generic structs or closures.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, it will be just one concrete implementation in the main target and one mock in the test target. If you don't inject through an interface, you're done with trying to unit test anything. That above is an example of usage, but you can imagine the real scenario can be more complex. I'll think about injecting the closure, but seems trouble for me in a long run with flow coordinators.

Comment: Protocols in order to mock something for tests is almost always a mistake. It's too much baggage and complexity for too little gain. Most mocked objects are classes, as they are here, and so should be mocked through subclassing, not protocols. DownloadPermissionCoordinator should just be the class itself, and MockDownloadPermissionCoordinator would subclass it. Alternately, you can swap out entire implementations by including different source files in the test target. Or you can make the thing to be mocked more configurable so it can be its own mock. But protocols are a bad solution for this.

Comment: Ended up injecting the completion from the start method in the constructor. Unfortunately subclassing for testing has its own downsides which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Ah, injecting a closure is often a very good solution. I often do this with a default parameter, so that normal callers don't have to provide it, but unit tests may.